# MediaPlayer IllegalStateException in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, illegalstateexception

I have SurfaceView and i play video from sdcard.When video is finished i try to show image 5 second and then play again my video.when i run my app and video has finished i have IllegalStateException

```
 videoSurface = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.videoSurface);
    videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);

    player = new MediaPlayer();
    controller = new VideoControllerView(this);
    player.setOnPreparedListener(this);


    try {
        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myvideo/Sample.mp4";
        player.setDataSource(filePath);
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                videoSurface.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                findViewById(R.id.imageView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                findViewById(R.id.imageView).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                videoSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        });
                        player.start();

                    }
                }, 5000);

            }
        });
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    controller.show();
    return false;
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    player.setDisplay(holder);
    player.prepareAsync();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return player.getCurrentPosition();
}

@Override
public int getDuration() {
    return player.getDuration();
}

@Override
public boolean isPlaying() {
    return player.isPlaying();
}

@Override
public void pause() {
    player.pause();
}

@Override
public void seekTo(int i) {
    player.seekTo(i);
}

@Override
public void start() {
    player.start();
}

@Override
public boolean isFullScreen() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void toggleFullScreen() {

}
```

maybe problem is in this line

```
videoSurface.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

what am i doing wrong in my code?

Comment: post your logcat errorlog

Comment: What if you comment out changing surface visibility inside onCompletionListener (two times)? I believe that the changing of visibility triggers some callbacks (onSurfaceChanged, for example) what puts the player in invalid state.

Answer (score 0):

Try `player.release()` in `onComplation` before `player.start()`